# If the result of my integral is of the form $ \ln(\infty)-ln(\infty) $ (they are the same functions), can i say that the integral evaluates to $0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

$$ \int f(t)dt=ln(\infty)-ln(\infty)= 0 $$

Can this be true?

If this is true, then these terms fall out and i can evaluate my integral better.

Comment: What does $\ln(\infty)$ even mean ?

Comment: Actually i just realized, they are a bit different, which means my propostion is wrong. It would mean $\ln(t+C)$ and $\ln(t-C)$, damn

Comment: This is unclear what is $C$ here ?

Comment: @Digitalis $C \in \mathbb{C}$ sorry for being unclear

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Comment: @PM 2Ring yes, i have just realized i can solve this convergence problem with limits, silly me

Comment: Understood. But the link in my comment may also be of benefit for future readers, so I'll leave it.

Comment: @PM2Ring It was very useful, now i know there is a place of collected problems like this!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually i just realized I can use Hospital's rule on $\ln(\frac{\infty}{\infty})$ to evaluate the 'combination' of the two infinities.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the question is asking but you may be interested in [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) which evaluates integrals of this form, take for example:
$$\lim_{h\to\infty}\int_{-h}^h\frac1xdx$$

Comment: this one seems like the specific version of the improper integral to me